# Ask if the screen is on/off in onStop() onPause()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle, android-broadcast

i want to know in my onPause() and onStop() method if it was called because the screen went off. Therefore i wrote a broadcastReceiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    public static boolean screenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

            screenOn = false;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

            screenOn = true;
        }
    }

}

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate() {

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        if (ScreenReceiver.screenOn) {

            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED OFF");
        } else {

        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        if (!ScreenReceiver.screenOn) {

            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED ON");
        } else {

        }
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

how is it possible if onPause() was called, because of switching the screen off ?

maybe with this ?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Whats the question again ???

Comment: how to know in onPause() if its called because the Power button was pressed and the screen went off

Comment: is your solution working?

Comment: no the receiver is called after onPause() and i don't like the solution with the power button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i got it i use now

```
 pm =(PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 if (pm.isScreenOn() == false) { ... }
```